# Unable to access Instagram messages from Facebook Graph API Explorer

Tags: rest, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to access Instagram messages from the Facebook Graph API Explorer.

With v14.0 I make the GET call `me/conversations?platform=instagram`. I get the following error:

```
  "error": {
    "message": "(#298) Reading mailbox messages requires the extended permission read_mailbox",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 298,
    "fbtrace_id": "Ad8l_IyomTnyotlNMG_HiS8"
  }
}
```

However, there is no `read_mailbox` permission in the Graph API Explorer Permissions. I checked under **App Review > Permissions and Features**, and couldn't find the `read_mailbox` permission there either.

Note that this API call works in the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pi2KxYeGMXo&t=18s, where they are using API v12.0, and the `read_mailbox` permission isn't required for that.

How do I get the `read_mailbox` permission or work around it?

Comment: I'm guessing you used the wrong kind of token - so that the alias `me` resolves to a user, instead of a page.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe! When I specified a Page Access token instead of a User token it worked. If you can put that as an answer I'll mark it approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "message": "(#298) Reading mailbox messages requires the extended permission read_mailbox",

That permission existed in the early days of the API, when it was still possible to read the mailbox of a user account.

Since you are getting that message here, this indicates that you tried to use a user access token, instead of a page token. (What the alias `me` resolves to, depends on the access token.)